# SOAP API - Retrieve private chats

Tags: soap-api, chatter

I am an admin trying to query all the private messages for my organization through SOAP API. I query the ChatterMessage object:

```
SELECT Id, ConversationId, SenderId, SendingNetworkId, Body, SentDate, CreatedById FROM ChatterMessage
```

where this returns the messages that is sent under the Chatter object. However, there is a chat box that does not log the messages under the object ChatterMessage. The documentation states that this object is used for private chat messages but the chat box conversations are not stored in this object. How can private chat messages be retrieved and which object contains this info? The only chatter hierarchy is related to feeds is found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/RelationshipsOfChatterObjects.htm).

Comment: What I meant was chats through the chat box.
http://imgur.com/RAX31tf
Other private messages are logged in the object ChatterMessage.

Comment: The chats in the chat box are not available through the API, unfortunately. The ChatterMessage object is for a different feature called Chatter Messages.